# Java : how to create java.security.Key from .asc file?

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key

I have to encrypt a file to **pgp format**. I have my **public key in .asc format**.

The cipher init() method  needs a public key to be passed in. What is way to create that key using a file. In my case it is .asc file.

```
    Cipher cipher;
    Key publicKey = null;

    try 
    {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");




    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        String msg = "failed to create output stream";
        LOGGER.error( msg, e );
        throw new RuntimeException( msg, e );
    }

    try {
        publicKey = getPublicKey(publicKeyPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ( new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher));
```

**I am getting error: 
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format**

My getPublicKey method looks like ( But I think , I do not have to do it this way as the file has the public key itself)

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String filename)
        throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());

        X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
          new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePublic(spec);
      }
```

Public_key.asc looks like :

```
            -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
            Version: Encryption Desktop 10.3.2 (Build 16127)

            mQENBFYhXNoBCACgX/u03wm8cLqmTZiKGx6H/1ZUoBsfaDB2rdG2D8jYQzvaq4MA
            hZWBEVhA2BGKrNI+a2SDhKGAY4OK7aUZVAVG1bfQNVdNe80TbEF8g/wO2FreYPkb
            ojPtkwgyzsvb1BKwgRM1UMjkM5OWnhAPDhFDc39SFbmHLsXrURqFqJd9T3xzF6ty

            ................................................................


            D4WXvHpPXCJcwCBe+/81ZpjxlrLkUu8bO79jxZdKcI5ZRpmIe/VPJoDUVKLvl9n3
            ANvDJGdGcW3x6RyL9QOnoRDf6njimqcTm8UqImdLCz4TFdv94dvM4K0NOWuFdYal
            E9Q+U0Q7aiaWn+Kt+OYpd6++m7wnJRH/q0H69LIR9v3Td3udzOaxv/gzXF1BFuAS
            DQs6iA==
            =ckOV
            -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Here are the properties of this key:

[image]

Comment: You can't use a public key with AES. AES is a symmetric cipher with a random key of 128, 192, or 256 bits. A public key is RSA, EC, or other asymmetric algorithm. Like dropping batteries in your gas tank.

Comment: You need special PGP key loader, because X.509 is incompatible with PGP regarding the key format.

Comment: Why not use the PGP functionality within Bouncy Castle?

Comment: I used org.bouncycastle.openpgp* lib to implemet this which worked perfectly fine until I tested with 10GB file to encrypt/decrypt. As this api holds data in memory after compress/de-compress, we saw java heap space error as result with big file.

Comment: I think Maarten was proposing to use BouncyCastle for loading the key (which is what you have asked for). Afterwards you can use BouncyCastle's `JcaPGPKeyConverter` to make java.security.PublicKey/PrivateKey from it and use it for whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks it worked that way. I will be searching for an improvement though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply from Robert and Maarten Bodewes is one of the ways to go.

My public key was in .asc file and private key in .skr ( secret key ring)

I implemented it this way and it worked for me:

```
                public static PublicKey getPublicKey(
                    String filePath)
                    throws PGPException, NoSuchProviderException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
                {
                    PGPPublicKey    encKey = readPublicKey(new FileInputStream(filePath));
                    return new JcaPGPKeyConverter().setProvider("BC").getPublicKey(encKey);
                }




                public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey( 
                        InputStream    in, char[]      passwd) 
                        throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException 
                    { 
                        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in); 

                        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection        pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(in); 

                        // 
                        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real 
                        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this. 
                        // 

                        // 
                        // iterate through the key rings. 
                        // 
                        Iterator<?> rIt = pgpSec.getKeyRings(); 

                        while (rIt.hasNext()) 
                        { 
                            PGPSecretKeyRing    kRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing)rIt.next();     
                            Iterator<?>                        kIt = kRing.getSecretKeys(); 

                            while (kIt.hasNext()) 
                            { 
                                PGPSecretKey    k = (PGPSecretKey)kIt.next(); 

                                if (k != null) 
                                { 
                                    PGPPrivateKey pk = k.extractPrivateKey(passwd, "BC"); 
                                     return new JcaPGPKeyConverter().setProvider("BC").getPrivateKey(pk);
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 

                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find secured key in key ring."); 
                    } 

                public static PGPPublicKey readPublicKey( 
                        InputStream    in) 
                        throws IOException, PGPException 
                    { 
                        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in); 

                        PGPPublicKeyRingCollection        pgpPub = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(in); 

                        // 
                        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real 
                        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this. 
                        // 

                        // 
                        // iterate through the key rings. 
                        // 
                        Iterator<?> rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings(); 

                        while (rIt.hasNext()) 
                        { 
                            PGPPublicKeyRing    kRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing)rIt.next();     
                            Iterator<?>                        kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys(); 

                            while (kIt.hasNext()) 
                            { 
                                PGPPublicKey    k = (PGPPublicKey)kIt.next(); 

                                if (k.isEncryptionKey()) 
                                { 
                                    return k; 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 

                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find encryption key in key ring."); 
                    }
```

Comment: what is bountycastle provider you have used ?, would you mind to provide maven dependency